# Dax code for multiplay rows

Tags: powerpivot, dax

It is possible to write dax code for the next request:

If at "status_new" column appears "active" take "testerName" cell data--> remove the last two characters "G1" (Always G1) and search for the same date at "MTDate" column (I always have two identical dates per tester name one time is for "XXXXG1" testers and second one is for "XXXX" testers),---> After we found this row check tester status if it "Active" leave the cell empty if it something else paste "Active".

```
MTDate  TesterName  Day TesterHostname  TesterFamily    status  G1_STATUS   MASTER_STATUS   Master_new1 STATUS_NEW  Status_updated
4/27/2017 20:00 CMT0441 27  HA04TCMT0441W7  CMT Active      Active          Active
4/27/2017 20:00 CMT0441G1   27  HA04TCMT0441G7  CMT Active  Active          Active  Active
4/27/2017 19:45 CMT0441G1   27  HA04TCMT0441G7  CMT Active  Active          Active  Active
4/27/2017 19:45 CMT0441 27  HA04TCMT0441W7  CMT Active      Active          Active
4/27/2017 19:30 CMT0441 27  HA04TCMT0441W7  CMT Inactive        Inactive            Inactive
4/27/2017 19:30 CMT0441G1   27  HA04TCMT0441G7  CMT Inactive    Inactive                
4/27/2017 19:15 CMT0441 27  HA04TCMT0441W7  CMT Inactive        Inactive            Inactive
4/27/2017 19:15 CMT0441G1   27  HA04TCMT0441G7  CMT Inactive    Inactive                
4/27/2017 19:00 CMT0441 27  HA04TCMT0441W7  CMT Inactive        Inactive            Inactive
4/27/2017 19:00 CMT0441G1   27  HA04TCMT0441G7  CMT Inactive    Inactive                
4/27/2017 18:45 CMT0441 27  HA04TCMT0441W7  CMT Inactive        Inactive            Inactive
4/27/2017 18:45 CMT0441G1   27  HA04TCMT0441G7  CMT Inactive    Inactive                
4/27/2017 18:30 CMT0441 27  HA04TCMT0441W7  CMT Inactive        Inactive            Inactive
4/27/2017 18:30 CMT0441G1   27  HA04TCMT0441G7  CMT Inactive    Inactive                
4/27/2017 18:15 CMT0441 27  HA04TCMT0441W7  CMT Active      Active          Active
4/27/2017 18:15 CMT0441G1   27  HA04TCMT0441G7  CMT Inactive    Inactive                
4/27/2017 18:00 CMT0441 27  HA04TCMT0441W7  CMT Active      Active          Active
4/27/2017 18:00 CMT0441G1   27  HA04TCMT0441G7  CMT Inactive    Inactive                
4/27/2017 17:45 CMT0441 27  HA04TCMT0441W7  CMT Active      Active          Active
4/27/2017 17:45 CMT0441G1   27  HA04TCMT0441G7  CMT Inactive    Inactive                
4/27/2017 17:30 CMT0441G1   27  HA04TCMT0441G7  CMT Inactive    Inactive                
4/27/2017 17:30 CMT0441 27  HA04TCMT0441W7  CMT Active      Active          Active
4/27/2017 17:15 CMT0441G1   27  HA04TCMT0441G7  CMT Inactive    Inactive                
4/27/2017 17:15 CMT0441 27  HA04TCMT0441W7  CMT Active      Active          Active
```

I tried to do it with "IF" command but I found deadlock time after time.

Comment: I failed to paste the data as table but if you copping it to excel it looks ok.

Comment: Does this actually have anything to do with PowerPoint? If not, you might want to remove the powerpoint tag.

Comment: Do you have a reason to this kind of updates in DAX and not in power query.